# Image gallery website best practices

Tags: node.js, express, hosting, cdn

We are developing a web application/mobile app that is primarily based on images and galleries. The front end is Backbone Marionette and Bootstrap and back end is Node.js, Express and Mongoose.

While we are developing it from scratch, my question is what are the best practices to store the images, display them, choosing server and hosting solutions (like CDN)? Will appreciate some suggestions from experts.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question? Asking the StackOverflow community to design/describe an image storage system is too broad.

Comment: You are correct and I follow the guidelines. However, here I couldn't come up with a specific problem and I just wanted to know, while I and my team is building a Gallery type web app that will deal with lots of images, what (say a list of 3-4 points) should be the best practices to follow.

For example, say "preloading the images" or "image resizing" etc. While I see already 3 "close votes", I guess most developers born with such best practice ideas.

Comment: The question is far too broad. There's not an industry "best practice" for your business requirements for storing and manipulating images. Many might consider their solutions to be confidential as well.

Comment: I understand. However, probably someone can share his experience on a similar app. Like, I appreciate the answer Samora shared.

Answer (score 4):

I will highly recommend using [Transloadit](http://transloadit.com). It can handle all image processing and even upload to your Amazon S3 bucket. It can even handle video processing and uploads if you decide to add that functionality later.

**Note:** I am in no way affiliated with [Transloadit](http://transloadit.com). Just a fan of their service and I personally use it in a few node.js apps.